# Unix: Subsetting data - Selecting rows based on (multiple) values in a column

Tags: unix, awk

I have a .tsv file that I would like to filter in Unix .

I want to select the rows that have certain numerical values (e.g 30700, 10600, ... etc) in a particular column.

Thus far, I have seen examples online where rows have been selected based on one particular value in a column. However, in my case, a particular column can have about 20-30 accepted values. How do I go about the subsetting of my data in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ if ($1 == 1 || $1 == 2) print $0; }'
```

would do the trick; but nobody gets promoted for writing 40 term if statements; so you might <strike>like to consider:</strike>

```
BEGIN { a[1] = a[2] = 1; }
{ if (a[$1]) print $0; }
```

as a template. 
*look at Ed's solution instead.*

Nice thing about awk; it is such a flexible language that there are probably dozens of different ways to approach this.  The difficult thing about awk; it is such a flexible language that there are probably dozens of different ways to approach this.

Comment: `if (a[$1])` will fill `a[]` with every `$1` from the input and so use far more memory (and be slower) than if you use `if ($1 in a)` instead.

Comment: yup; my bad testing....

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is:

```
BEGIN {
    split("30700 10600",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        vals[tmp[i]]
    }
    FS = "\t"
}
$1 in vals
```